# Add UIPageControl to UIPageViewController via storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I try to create onboarding page by following this [tutorial](https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/need-to-create-an-onboarding-flow-for-your-mobile-app-heres-how-to-do-it-using-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift/) and it works great.

That link suggest to create every page onboarding as single view controller using storyboard, then wrap it on my class which is subclass of `UIPageViewController`.

By following that tutorial, I already created nice onboarding page but there is one question remaining. Basically, I created each page of my onboarding pages using storyboard and create its class subclassing `UIViewController`. Then I dragged `UIPageViewController` which is my initial view controller. The result is created onboarding page that has black dot indicator on bottom page. I try to move that indicator and modify it, but still has no clue.

So my first step is remove implementation of its datasource method `presentationCountForPageViewController` and `presentationIndexForPageViewController`, my indicator has disappear.

My question is, where should I add `UIPageControl` so my onboarding page doesn't use its bottom indicator?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `UIPageViewController` is not the best idea. Better is to create a container view controller for `UIPageViewController` that will conform to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`. Using storyboard you can add to you container view controller's view a container view that load your `UIPageViewController`. Get your `UIPageViewController` from `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method to configure. 
Now you're able to manage your `UIPageViewController` from container view controller. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up with create View Controller that conform `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` by following this http://samwize.com/2016/03/08/using-uipageviewcontroller-with-custom-uipagecontrol/